# The django admin page can not show the related icons rightly

Tags: django, django-admin

I used the dev environment to run the django server:

```
$python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But the related icons in the admin page can not show rightly:

[image]

I think the parameters in my `settings.py` are not correctly , can any body help me how to set it ?

The followings are the contents of my `settings.py`:

```
import os

_ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'zl0djft^%oq8toum-*9o^m#bg38st%q0k8n@1o5_2gz#pk20'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'CI',
    'CT',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ibuildmaster.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(_ROOT_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ibuildmaster.wsgi.application'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(_ROOT_PATH, 'static'), 
)


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And the contents of my 'urls.py' :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^'  , include('CI.urls')),
    url(r'^CI/', include('CI.urls')),
    url(r'^CT/', include('CT.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Please read [serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

Comment: Thanks，I tried accordance with the manual : 

add django.contrib.staticfiles to the INSTALLED_APPS , define STATIC_URL = '/static/'

and tried  STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"   +  $ python manage.py collectstatic 

but it not works , I installed my django in the Windows environment , and the related files are under C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin

Comment: I used Django1.9 + Python2.7 in Windows environment , and all the missing image URL is like : http://10.0.3.38:8000/static/admin/img/search.svg   which is under my django installed folder : C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin

Comment: I really appreciate if anyone can help on it  T_T

Comment: please update the question with your `urls.py`

Comment: thanks , I added  the contents of my root urls.py at the end of my question

Comment: My friend you need to [read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) and fix your `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

For me the static files are served correctly in admin page, please check browser settings or file/folder permission